# generate forms from models in CAKEPHP

Tags: forms, orm, cakephp

hey has anyone successfully done this, do you have a simple example of this? the goal is to build a frontend to create the form thus the form variables being saved in the database.

do i need to know what fields are being saved /mirror with another table or can one do this in the same table?

Comment: Aren't you essentially trying to recreate scaffolding? Sounds like what you're after is exactly what scaffolding provides, but you don't include much detail.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are searching for [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/113/Code-Generation-with-Bake)?

Comment: well kind of, im looking for a solution that does that for the user with a frontend, being dependent on the model at all times